# Export QGIS2Web

Tags: qgis

Please help me how to export OS basemap in Qgis2web because when I am trying to export its not happening. Please check this picture for the reference.

[image]

Comment: Please add relevant details on how you are going about the export.

Comment: You mean details of what??

Comment: How did you add the OS Basemap? what settings did you use in qgis2web?

Comment: I have added the basemap through WMS/WMTS and used their api link to load in qgis.

Answer (score 0):

We need more details. A possible explanation is that your map projection is not supported by the WMS. If your map export format is not OpenLayers, that won't work. Only OpenLayers projects rasters client-side.